# Unable to delete RDS cluster due to false error about pending maintainence?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a RDS cluster which is stuck in a weird state. It is telling me that i have a pending upgrade even though there is none that i can see. I am trying to delete my cluster but when i select delete i get the following error message :-

```
The cluster arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:cluster:aurora-cluster-demo is upgrading or has pending upgrade; please retry the request once the cluster has finished the upgrade
```

which is clearly not the case since there is no pending maintenance that i can see on the UI and neither via the CLI.

[image]

and checking the pending maintenance via the CLI shows nothing either :

```
aws rds describe-pending-maintenance-actions --resource-identifier arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:cluster:aurora-cluster-demo
{
"PendingMaintenanceActions": []
}
```

Comment: Can you Stop the cluster?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you but this is eventually what i ended up doing haha. Stopped it and then deleted it. I would still gladly accept your answer if you post it :) because this was kinda the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to **Stop** the database, then you might be able to **Delete** the cluster.

Quite strange, as your dashboard is showing that there are zero instances in the cluster anyway!